# Jenkins: line 5: pytest: command not found

Tags: python, jenkins, pytest

I am trying to run a unit test in Jenkins (Jenkins isn't being run locally) for a python script using pytest.

My Jenkins congif file pulls source code from bitbucket, and in the build section I selected `Execute shell` with the following commands.

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install numpy
pip3 install pytest
pytest test.py
```

The error I get is

```
/home/jenkins/tmp/jenkins6809923023096290887.sh: line 5: pytest: command not found
```

I notice that pytest is installed, but in a different folder as reported in a preceding line:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pytest in /home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (6.0.1)
```

Can anyone help with how to get Jenkins to run pytest from the necessary directory? More generally, does anyone know of up to date tutorials on using pytest with Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

Better off explicitly calling your version of Python as shown below.

```
python3.6 -m pip --upgrade pip
python3.6 -m pip install numpy pytest
python3.6 -m pytest test.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @gold_cy for their answer. It didn't work for me, but the following did work

```
pip3 --install --upgrade pip
pip3 install numpy pytest
python -m pytest test.py
```

I believe the reason this works is in accordance with the [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/usage.html#cmdline) ...

> [Calling via python] is almost equivalent to invoking the command line script pytest [...] directly, except that calling via python will also add the current directory to sys.path.